# Perl 6 calculate the average of an int array at once using reduce

Tags: functional-programming, raku

I'm trying to calculate the average of an integer array using the reduce function in one step. I can't do this:

```
say (reduce {($^a + $^b)}, <1 2 3>) / <1 2 3>.elems;
```

because it calculates the average in 2 separate pieces.

I need to do it like:

```
say reduce {($^a + $^b) / .elems}, <1 2 3>;
```

but it doesn't work of course.

How to do it in one step? (Using map or some other function is welcomed.)

Comment: Here is one example: `given <1 2 3> { say (reduce {($^a + $^b)}, $_ >>/>> $_.elems) };`

Comment: That works. The last part (the `>>/>>` usage in particular) needs some explanation, though.

Comment: It is called a hyper operator, see [Hyper operators](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#Hyper_operators) for more information

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**TL;DR** This answer starts with an idiomatic way to write equivalent code before discussing P6 flavored "tacit" programming and increasing brevity. I've also added "bonus" footnotes about the hyperoperation Håkon++ used in their first comment on your question.<sup>5</sup>

## Perhaps not what you want, but an initial idiomatic solution

We'll start with a simple solution.<sup>1</sup>

P6 has built in routines<sup>2</sup> that do what you're asking. Here's a way to do it using built in `sub`s:

```
say { sum($_) / elems($_) }(<1 2 3>); # 2
```

And here it is using corresponding<sup>3</sup> `method`s:

```
say { .sum / .elems }(<1 2 3>); # 2
```

## What about "functional programming"?

First, let's replace `.sum` with an explicit reduction:

```
.reduce(&[+]) / .elems
```

When `&` is used at the start of an expression in P6 you know the expression refers to a `Callable` as a [first class citizen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen).

A longhand way to refer to the infix `+` operator as a function value is `&infix:<+>`. The shorthand way is `&[+]`.

As you clearly know, the `reduce` routine takes a binary operation as an argument and applies it to a list of values. In method form (`invocant.reduce`) the ["invocant"](https://docs.raku.org/language/101-basics#index-entry-invocant_%28Basics%29-invocant) is the list.

The above code calls two methods -- `.reduce` and `.elems` -- that have no explicit invocant. This is a form of ["tacit" programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming); methods written this way implicitly (or ["tacitly"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22tacitly%22)) use [$_](https://docs.raku.org/syntax/$_) (aka "the topic" or simply "it") as their invocant.

## Topicalizing (explicitly establishing what "it" is)

`given` binds a single value to `$_` (aka "it") for a single statement or block.

(That's *all* `given` does. Many other keywords also topicalize but do something else too. For example, `for` binds *a series of values* to `$_`, not just one.)

Thus you could write:

```
say .reduce(&[+]) / .elems given <1 2 3>; # 2
```

Or:

```
$_ = <1 2 3>;
say .reduce(&[+]) / .elems; # 2
```

But given that your focus is FP, there's another way that you should know.

## Blocks of code and "it"

First, wrap the code in a block:

```
{ .reduce(&[+]) / .elems }
```

The above is a [`Block`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Block), and thus a lambda. Lambdas without a signature get a default [signature](https://docs.raku.org/type/Signature) that accepts one *optional* argument.

Now we could again use `given`, for example:

```
say do { .reduce(&[+]) / .elems } given <1 2 3>; # 2
```

But we can also just use ordinary function call syntax:

```
say { .reduce(&[+]) / .elems }(<1 2 3>)
```

Because a postfix `(...)` calls the [`Callable`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Callable) on its left, and because in the above case one argument is passed in the parens to a block that expects one argument, the net result is the same as the `do`<sup>4</sup> and the `given` in the prior line of code.

## Brevity with built ins

Here's another way to write it:

```
<1 2 3>.&{.sum/.elems}.say; #2
```

This calls a block as if it were a method. Imo that's still eminently readable, especially if you know P6 basics.

Or you can start to get silly:

```
<1 2 3>.&{.sum/$_}.say; #2
```

This is still readable *if you know P6*. The `/` is a numeric (division) operator. Numeric operators coerce their operands to be numeric. In the above `$_` is bound to `<1 2 3>` which is a list. And in Perls, a collection in numeric context is its number of elements.

## Changing P6 to suit you

So far I've stuck with standard P6.

You can of course write `sub`s or `method`s and name them using any Unicode letters. If you want single letter aliases for `sum` and `elems` then go ahead:

```
my (&s, &e) = &sum, &elems;
```

But you can also extend or change the language as you see fit. For example, you can create user defined operators:

```
#| LHS ⊛ RHS.
#| LHS is an arbitrary list of input values.
#| RHS is a list of reducer function, then functions to be reduced.
sub infix:<⊛> (@lhs, *@rhs (&reducer, *@fns where *.all ~~ Callable)) {
  reduce &reducer, @fns».(@lhs)
}
say <1 2 3> ⊛ (&[/], &sum, &elems); # 2
```

I won't bother to explain this for now. (Feel free to ask questions in the comments.) My point is simply to highlight that you can introduce arbitrary ([prefix, infix, circumfix, etc.](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#Operator_classification)) operators.

And if custom operators aren't enough you can change [*any* of the rest of the syntax](https://modules.raku.org/search/?q=slang). cf ["braid"](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammingLanguages/comments/a4z68q/what_principles_have_you_adopted_for_your/eblgbzn/).

## Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> This is how I would normally write code to do the computation asked for in the question. @timotimo++'s comment nudged me to alter my presentation to start with that, and only then shift gears to focus on a more FPish solution.

<sup>2</sup> In P6 all built in functions are referred to by the generic term "routine" and are instances of a sub-class of [`Routine`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Routine) -- typically a [`Sub`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Sub) or [`Method`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Method).

<sup>3</sup> Not all built in `sub` routines have correspondingly named `method` routines. And vice-versa. Conversely, sometimes there *are* correspondingly named routines but they don't work exactly the same way (with the most common difference being whether or not the first argument to the `sub` is the same as the "invocant" in the method form.) In addition, you can *call a subroutine as if it were a method* using the syntax `.&foo` for a named `Sub` or `.&{ ... }` for an anonymous `Block`, or *call a method `foo` in a way that looks rather like a subroutine call* using the syntax `foo invocant:` or `foo invocant: arg2, arg3` if it has arguments beyond the invocant.

<sup>4</sup> If a block is used where it should obviously be invoked then it is. If it's not invoked then you can use an explicit `do` statement prefix to invoke it.

<sup>5</sup> Håkon's first comment on your question used "hyperoperation". With just one easy to recognize and remember ["metaop"](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#Metaoperators) (for unary operations) or a pair of them (for binary operations), [hyperoperations](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#Hyper_operators) distribute an operation to all the "leaves"<sup>6</sup> of a data structure (for an unary) or create a new one based on pairing up the "leaves" of a pair of data structures (for binary operations). NB. Hyperoperations are done in parallel<sup>7</sup>.

<sup>6</sup> What is a "leaf" for a hyperoperation is determined by a combination of the operation being applied (see [the `is nodal` trait](https://docs.raku.org/routine/is%20nodal)) and whether a particular element is [`Iterable`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Iterable).

<sup>7</sup> Hyperoperation is applied in parallel, at least semantically. Hyperoperation assumes<sup>8</sup> that the operations on the "leaves" have no mutually interfering side-effects -- that is to say, that any side effect when applying the operation to one "leaf" can safely be ignored in respect to applying the operation to any another "leaf".

<sup>8</sup> By using a hyperoperation the developer is declaring that the assumption of no meaningful side-effects is correct. The compiler will act on the basis it is, but will not check that it is true. In the safety sense it's like a loop with a condition. The compiler will follow the dev's instructions, even if the result is an infinite loop.

Comment: don't forget there's also `.sum` which is a whole lot shorter than `.reduce(&[+])` and maybe a little clearer

Comment: @timotimo Yeah, that was my first thought, but... Well, no buts, I've rewritten my answer. Thx for the nudge. :)

Comment: @raiph Yes I'm after the functional ways to carry out the list operations in the shortest and at the same time most expressive manner. 'at once' actually means that :) Morphing the `do` and the `given` duo into a normal function call, I see for the first time and it's quite useful in this case.

Comment: say {([+] $_) / + $_}(<1 2 3>) ... if you prefer brevity to readability

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example using [given](https://docs.raku.org/language/control#given) and [the reduction meta operator](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#Reduction_metaoperators):

```
given <1 2 3> { say ([+] $_)/$_.elems } ;
```

Comment: So it seems, the `given` keyword does the trick I guess. Because it allows the calculation to be done in one step :)

Comment: And actually, you don't even need the `.elems`; `given @foo { ([+] $_) / $_ }`; works just fine (as does using `with`, if we can assume it'll be defined)

Comment: Piggybacking on @guifa's comment: As @raiph explains, that's because `/` is a Numeric operator and thus it interprets its operands in a numeric context. Here `$_` is a listy thing and its numeric value is just the number of elements it holds (i.e., `.elems`). More info: https://docs.perl6.org/language/contexts#Number